# How to set a profile that only allows selected calls through?

Tags: calls, call-screening, profiles

I work on the third shift, so I sleep during the day. But I get calls all day long, so I shut my ringer off.  I would like to be able to allow a couple of phone numbers that can ring through no matter what.

Using Google Voice to do this won't work because I get calls directly to my cell number as well as to Google Voice.

How to set a profile that only allows selected calls through?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Setting Profiles](http://www.probeez.com/) app can do that. From their site:

> **What if I don’t want to miss an important call while I’m on mute?**
>
> You can overwrite current sound
>   settings with a rule based on Incoming
>   Call condition. Here is how to:
>
> - Create a new rule
> - Add Incoming Call condition and set it to your preferred contacts group (like VIP or Family)
> - Add Activate Profile action to activate the profile where sound is On and/or some custom ring tone specified
>
> That’s it! Now even if your phone is
>   set to mute, it will still ring in
>   case of a call from someone from
>   Contact Group you have set up in step
>   two.

They currently have two versions of the app - a [Lite](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.probeez.liteprofiles) and [Full](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.probeez.profiles). I would try the Lite version to see if it has this feature first.

QR Code for Setting Profiles Lite:

[image: QR Code for Setting Profiles Lite]

QR Code for Setting Profiles Full:

[image: QR Code for Setting Profiles Full]

Comment: Awesome thanks!  The last time I bothered searching for this was in the spring and I don't think this app was out yet.

Answer (score 0):

I use "Shh! Auto-Silencer" for a similar purpose, screening notification automatically (so I don't get calls at work rather than while sleeping).

It is a time profile based app that silences your phone between time A and B and allows you to set exception for contacts. The best thing about it is that it runs in the background (boot on start-up and runs off the alarm clock service), you don't need to enable/disable it as a sound mode.

[image]

- [Shh!auto-silencer lite](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-zeus-chut-iqwn.aspx)