# Send all calls to Voice Mail

Tags: htc-desire, calls, voicemail

It's seems like it should be a simple thing, but I haven't figured it out yet on my desire.

How do I send all calls to voice mail?  I can disable the mobile data network and put the phone in airplane mode, but how do I keep the data active and send all calls to voice mail?

Comment: related: [How to set a profile that only allows selected calls through?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/243/any-apps-that-will-allow-me-to-set-a-profile-that-only-allows-emergency-calls-thr)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't have the option Matthew Read suggested, you could use a [call blocking app](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=call+block).  Most of them have an option to block all calls.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think to simple search for an app.  I guess I was stuck on what I thought should be an easy option somewhere obvious.

Comment: I went through the same thought process a couple months ago.  It just doesn't make sense that they wouldn't have a built in setting for this.

Answer (score 2):

Settings -> Call -> Call Forwarding -> Always Forward -> Your voicemail number

Every phone I've ever seen has that option.

Comment: Would work but is cumbersome.

Answer (score 2):

Turn the ringer volume to zero/set to not even vibrate.

This is slightly facetious answer, as the user will still hear the ring, and have to wait for Voice Mail to pick up, so it is probably not the ideal solution; but it's what I do when I'm in a movie or church or something.

Answer (score 1):

```
Settings -> Wireless and network -> Mobile networks
```

or

```
Settings -> Wireless Controls -> Mobile Network Settings -> Mode of Operation
```

There should be a "Data only", "EVDO only", or similar option in there, *depending on your phone*.  My T-Mobile Vibrant does not have this option, for example, [but the HTC Hero does](http://androidforums.com/sprint-htc-hero/29215-send-all-calls-voicemail-automatically.html).

Another possibility is:

```
Settings -> Call settings -> Voice call
```

There should be "Call forwarding" or "Call barring" options there that might do it, though they are greyed out for me.

Comment: First two don't exist for me on my phone.  Third works but is cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Google Voice, there is a simple "Do Not Disturb" option.

Comment: Does that work too if you are using GV for your cell # voicemail too?  I was going to test it out but I assumed that it wouldn't because unlike a real GV number its not being routed through Google system and would be able to head calls off at the pass.  Right?

Comment: Good point. No, it doesn't intercept it. But I only give out my GV number, so this is an option that works for me.