# Only allow forwarded calls

Tags: cyanogenmod, call-screening

My job requires that I am on call from time to time, and contactable 24/7. There is an on-call phone that I typically forward all calls through to my own personal device.

Is there a way in which I can allow only calls that were originally put through to the on-call phone while my phone is in quiet hours?

There's a [related question and answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/243/any-apps-that-will-allow-me-to-set-a-profile-that-only-allows-emergency-calls-th) about whitelisting certain numbers during quiet hours, but my problem is different as I could get called from any number.

If it helps, the on-call device is an iPhone 4S on the o2 network, and my device is a rooted Nexus 5 with Cyanogenmod 12 on Giffgaff (also o2).